# Messagebird returning 401 Unauthorized Error in My Bot using Microsoft Bot Framewerk C#

Tags: c#, botframework, whatsapp, messagebird

I am using net6.0 azure bot framework and able to connect with other default channel, however I am finding it difficult to connect to Messagebird. The number I am using is my own and it has been verified and I see that the message I am sending is getting to it, I also used ngrok set-up to configure my bot webhook and I see it is reaching it. However someowhere around the adapter handler and the controller which is not showing me the exact errror the bot is not responding but with unauthorized. I have confirmed my access key and sign key is correct as I used the same to set my bot webhook url and it was successful, I used https://conversations.messagebird.com/v1/webhooks as my MessageBirdWebhookEndpointUrl properties. Please what am I doing wrong here? Any helo will be appreciated. I set up the adapter handler, controller and injection as required in the bot community messagebird adapter version 4.31

I have tried using ngrok to see if my webhook is getting a response from messagebird and it is confirmed it is getting it. I traced the error between the controller and the adapter and it seems the adapter is not giving the right response to the controller hence the unauthorized but finding it hard to know what the issue is. I was expecting the bot will respond back and the send the response to the messagebird webhook, but it's coming back as unauthorized.